Show that $f(t) = t^2 + 4t + 2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F_5}$
I had a very short introduction to some exercises about finite fields, but I don't understand the theory very well, so I'm a bit confused.
I have this polynomial $t^2 + 4t + 2$ with coefficients that are elements of $\mathbb{F_5}$. I wanted to try a "brute force method" to proof irreducibility over $\mathbb{F_5}$. I calculated the discriminant of the polynomial and I wanted to conclude that there exists no $g(t),h(t)$ with $\deg(g(t)),\deg(h(t)) < 2$ such that $f(t) = g(t)h(t)$. Is this a good way to proof this? And do I need to do all necessary calculations mod $5$?

A polynomial of degree $2$ or $3$ over a field is reducible if and only if it has a root in this field. In this case, you can just check directly if it has a root in $\mathbb{F_5}$ or not. Just substitute all $5$ elements.

Did you know that the quadratic formula works just as well over any field (except characteristic 2)? You just have to reinterpret what fractions and square roots mean.

It may be easier to check that $(t+2)^2-2$ has no zeros in $\Bbb{F}_5$. Yes, you want to do the calculations modulo $5$, it's the whole point.

But surely we have covered if not exactly this question, then very similar ones. Did you search?

@Mark Thank you very much.

See for example here

@Arthur No, I wasn't aware of that but I'm curious now. I want to look into it. Thank you for your comment.

@JyrkiLahtonen I was looking at similar questions, but apparently not similar enough, there seem to be multiple ways to check irreducibility and they seemed a bit more technical.

With a quadratic modulo a prime $p>2$ all you need to check is whether the discriminant is a quadratic residue. When the degree goes up, it gets progressively more taxing (even though there are algorithms faster than those checking for primality).

A slightly simpler case, another one.
